# I click Post Your Question on Stack Overflow (not meta), but nothing happens

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, posting

I'm trying to post a question at Stack Overflow (not meta), but when I type Post Your Question, nothing happens, the question is not submitted. The question title is "contract IDs", the question body is "When you need to create or access well-known objects in XPCOM, where do you find their contract IDs?" and the questions tags are xpcom and contract-ids. What is going on?

UPDATE: maybe, you should make it so that if the title is too short, the post your question button is disabled.

Comment: "contract IDs" is a seriously bad question title. "Finding contract IDs in XPCOM" is what you want.

Comment: This should be status-bydesign ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/one-place-to-manage-daily-new-answer-notifications ). This shouldn't be status-bydesign ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/i-click-post-your-question-on-stack-overflow-not-meta-but-nothing-happens ). If you don't exchange the tags again, I will go back to Experts-Exchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title is too short.

http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/369/titletooshort.png

edit, oops, I didn't format the image correctly.

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/7852/image3m.png

Ahh, much better.

edit: We moved most of the post validation to the server, which helps reduce any client JavaScript quirks that would prevent submission. This also means submission errors can be simplified and placed in the same area on the form:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6915/stackoverflowserverside.png

Comment: This is why `<blink>` is sorely missed.

Comment: @Jeff -- follow the meme!  Where are the freehand circles?

Comment: How can you possibly forget the freehand circles when the meme question is so conveniently updated every day?

Comment: Actually, I **kinda like** the freehand Bézier curves...

Comment: I'm always happy to find someone who is even less talented as artist than I am.