# One place to manage daily new answer notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I don't know what questions I'm subscribed to and what questions I'm not subscribed to. I'm having to visit questions one-by-one to check or uncheck things. Please change this.

Comment: You should see any reactions to your questions or your comments using the "envelope" symbol above. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Pekka - it's not the OP's own questions or comments, it's other people's questions they've "subscribed" to. Though I'm not sure what this "subscribing" is. If it's the RSS feed, then the list will be in what ever RSS reader they use. If it's questions that have been "favourited" then these are on the OP's profile page.

Comment: Ah - it **is** the OP's own questions where he checked the "Notify me@example.com daily of any new answers" option.

Comment: This should be status-bydesign ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/one-place-to-manage-daily-new-answer-notifications ). This shouldn't be status-bydesign ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/i-click-post-your-question-on-stack-overflow-not-meta-but-nothing-happens ). If you don't exchange the tags again, I will go back to Experts-Exchange!

Comment: +1, it's must have feature

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't just click the envelope beside your name?

Comment: I don't think that is what he was referring to, although it is difficult to discern what exactly he is talking about.

Comment: He wants to be able to see all the questions where he checked the "Notify me@example.com daily of any new answers" option.

Comment: @chris I see, that makes more sense now