# Manage all SE questions in one place

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, stackexchange.com

I have a few SE accounts. I'd like to have the possibility to view my questions and filter and sort them all from stackexchange.com but there is not this possibility. You can only view your `top questions`.

The disadvantage of this approach is that users who are careful to have all their questions solved forget all the small (marginal) SE sites where they asked something. If they could view it from central place they could have better overview of their questions.

Is this going to be implemented?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/one-place-to-manage-daily-new-answer-notifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the **posts** section under [your **activity** tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/329709?tab=activity).

[image: Screenshot of the activity tab]

Comment: That's on a good way. It would be sufficient If I could filter posts that are `asked` but `unaccepted` yet (or at least to see the unaccepted status). In other words in this list is missing a lot of useful information. The sorting according to time from newest to oldest is OK - I like it.