# Post Your Question button grays out when clicked, then nothing, have to retype question

Tags: bug, asking-questions, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Post your question” fails on Opera 10.10 Win XP SP3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/post-your-question-fails-on-opera-10-10-win-xp-sp3)

Just today this happened three times to me. I click Ask Question, type my question, then hit Post Your Question. The button grays out, becoming unclickable but nothing happens. The submit did not succeed and to continue I have to ask the question again. Second time more luck.

Because it keeps happening, I decided to mention it here. I use Opera 10, latest version.

*PS: it happened with this very question as well..., and no, [none of these happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31230/i-click-post-your-question-on-stack-overflow-not-meta-but-nothing-happens), all fields are filled with acceptable data, the working q. is equal to the non-working question.*

Comment: Playing around with tag suggestions? Maybe this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19254/adding-tags-to-a-new-question-in-opera-broken

Comment: @random - unlike what is told in this question, though, you can still mess up this by clicking a tag suggestion, I think, in Opera 10. That's probably what went wrong here. Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/post-your-question-fails-on-opera-10-10-win-xp-sp3

Comment: Opera 10 (latest) has a problem with stackoverflow and posting questions.  The problem is not yet understood, but since it works in the other major browsers it may not get much attention.  Go upvote the question linked to by gnoupi so they can see how many people it affects.

Comment: Jeff should get himself a `[status-itsopera]` by now.

Comment: I would be fine with this if it were linked to a question that recognized this as a bug, which it really is, not only in Op 10.10, but also in Opera 10.51. Jeff incorrectly concludes in the referring thread that *"it is fine in Opera"*, while obviously it is not.